# Multiselct Dropdown in angular material2

Tags: angular, user-interface, multi-select, angular-material2

I am using angular material (https://material.angular.io) in my application.
I have tried with multiselect dropdown in material angular by using the chips (mat-chip-list). But I couldn't achieve it. Is there any one achieve it using angular material? If please share link or samples?

Comment: This might help you: https://cuppalabs.github.io/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/

Comment: This lib has more stars: http://softsimon.github.io/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But my requirement is to achieve the multi select dropdown using angular material2.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but see if it works for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/md2-multiselect

Comment: Material2 is extremely limited at the moment, you would be best looking for alternative while m2 is still in very early stages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already possible with Angular Material. Just add `multiple` or `[multiple]="true"` to your `mat-select`.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
      {{ option }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-beta12-qbyzr4?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Hi.This I have tried. But the selection of values in the  checkbox. I don't required the checkbox. This must be normal select option. Once the user selects the option, It must be appear in text box with 'x'. If i click on 'x'. It should close. In this user can select multiple also.So  Only i have tried with mat-chip-list. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3273#issuecomment-335089633